# Inicialização de Enum

Tags: c#, enums

Sempre criei `enums` assim:

```
public enum TipoTelefone
{
  Residencial,
  Celular,
  Comercial
}
```

Mas hoje dando manutenção em um código encontrei um assim:

```
public enum TipoTelefone
{
    Residencial = 0,
    Celular,
    Comercial
}
```

Qual a diferença de inicializar o primeiro elemento do `enum`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Por padrão, o valor associado as constantes dos membros da enumeração são do tipo `int`. A primeira variação começa como zero e é incrementada em um para cada variante seguinte. Portanto, neste exemplo:

```
enum TipoTelefone {
    Residencial,
    Celular,
    Comercial
}
```

O valor para cada variante é: `Residencial`, `0`; `Celular`, `1` e `Comercial`, `2`. Repare que é sequencial.

Mas também é possível definir explicitamente valores para os membros. Por exemplo:

```
enum ErrorCode {
    Residencial = 100,
    Celular = 200,
    Comercial = 300
}
```

Nesse caso, os membros têm valores definidos explicitamente. Não há mais sequência implícita no exemplo acima. No exemplo acima, parece-me meio desnecessário, mas pode ser útil em algumas situações específicas.

Já em casos como mostrado no exemplo da pergunta, no qual apenas o primeiro elemento é redefinido, os demais continuam seguindo a sua ordem, de modo sequencial.

Então, no exemplo abaixo, a definição de `Residencial` à `0` é redundante, já que o primeiro elemento é, por padrão, zero.

```
enum TipoTelefone {
    Residencial = 0,
    Celular,
    Comercial
}
```

Mas se fizer algo como:

```
enum TipoTelefone {
    Residencial = 5,
    Celular,
    Comercial
}
```

As variantes serão definidas a partir do 5. `Residencial`, `5`; `Celular`, `6` e `Comercial`, `7`.

Answer (score 3):

Esse caso muda nada. Apenas adotou o estilo mais explícito do que o compilador já faz por padrão. Quando nada é informado o primeiro valor é sempre 0 e os demais segue sendo sempre o valor do membro anterior + 1.

Faz mais sentido quando você quer valores diferentes do padrão.

E claro, se tiver um padrão muito estranho é melhor ser explícito em todos para ficar mais legível. Ou seja, opte pelo padrão implícito ou seja todo explícito.

Particularmente não gosto do meio termo que é o caso demonstrado, foi explícito em um caso e implícito nos outros.

Sempre pode haver caso para adotar uma mistura e mesmo esse caso não causou nenhum grande problema, mas eu prefiro ligeiramente mais o seu jeito. Cada caso posso agir diferente, essa é só uma tendência.
O meu conselho é evitar ao máximo adotar padrões diferentes de começar com 0 e cada membro ir adicionando 1 ou então ir em múltiplos, por exemplo cada membro ir dobrando de valor, em geral adotando o atributo [`[Flags]`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.flagsattribute?view=net-6.0). mas se o domínio pedir, não tem problema usar outros valores. Em alguns casos quando foge muito do padrão talvez um `enum` não seja o mais adequado. Esse é o mecanismo que vejo algum abuso.